# haskell parsing data structure with extra information

Tags: parsing, haskell, return-value

I have problem to extract extra information from my parsing.

I have my own data structure to parse, and that works fine. I wrote the parser for my data structure as `Parse MyDataStructure` which parse all the information about `MyDataStructure`.

The problem is that in the string I'm parsing, mixed with `MyDataStructure`, there is also  some information about what should I do with `MyDataStructure` which is of course not part of `MyDataStructure`, i.e. I cannot store this information inside `MyDataStructure`.

Now the problem is that I don't know how to store this information, since in Haskell I cannot change some global variable to store information, and the return value of my parser is already `MyDataStructure`.

Is there a way I can somehow store this new information, without changing `MyDataStructure`, i.e. including field to store the extra information (but the extra information are not part of `MyDataStructure` so I would really like avoiding doing that)?

I hope I have been clear enough.

Comment: Won't a tuple `(MyDataStructure, ExtraInfo)` work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @9000 says, you could use a tuple. If you find yourself needing to pass it through a number of functions, using the [State Monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad) might make things easier.